# Laravel Dynamic Query where equal to any value

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel, query-builder

Laravel normal query i try to make it dynamic without write all query again by if or so like this

```
$type = ....  some time  0 or 1 or 2

$user= User::where('type',$type)->get();
```

what i want is give $type value to get all user where they have type 0 or 1 or 2 something like '*' in select

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

`$user= User::whereIn('type',[0,1,2])->get();`

Comment: it may become random number . so i want it to accept any value

Comment: So you should go ahead and store those numbers in an array like `$type = [1,2,3,4] and then just use it in `whereIn`. If it helped, please mark the answer as correct so others can be helped.